# Opening downloaded file in mac OSx using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, macos, web

I have a link in a webpage, clicking on that link downloads the abc.mobileconfig file to downloads folder on mac OS. After downloading I have to open this file automatically so that mac OSx prompts a user for installing the profile.

How can I open this downloaded file using JavaScript which can be embedded in the webpage?

Comment: You can't access to local files using Javascript for security sake.

Comment: You can't, for a good reason: virus writers' job would be sooooo easy otherwise.

Comment: you can use a file input and FileReader to rip any user-chosen file, including that one.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same result using php or some other scripts? @dandavis can you please share some links about filereader and rip the files ?

Comment: just google "FileReader MDN" and you'll find several examples.